# How much does a radiator at 25˚C affect a room that is 20˚C?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, estimation

This is probably not a very precise question but I'm just trying to get a rough idea how much effect a radiator set at such a low temperature would have on a room. Let's assume that the number of radiators and size of the radiators is generally appropriate for the size of the room. Make up your own approximate values for these.

I want to get some idea whether it has some effect or is basically negligible in a real world application and if it does affect the room's temperature, how long would it take to do that.

Answer (score 2):

$25^{\circ}$ is of course a very low radiator temperature, $\approx 60^{\circ}$ being far more common.

But even at $25^{\circ}$ there's positive heat transfer going from the radiators to the room, as long as the room's temperature is below $25^{\circ}$)

[Newton's Law of cooling/heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law) is very enlightening here:

$$\dot{Q}=hA\left(T(t)-T_{env}\right)\tag{1}$$

(Please consult the link above for precise meaning of symbols) For this question $T_{env}$ is the **radiator temperature** (assumed constant at $25^{\circ}$)

Firstly and intuitively it's clear that heat transfer $\dot{Q}$ (flux - radiator to room) is greatly influenced by $T(t)-T_{env}$, so that:

$$\dot{Q}\propto\left(T(t)-T_{env}\right)$$

Here the Law is written for cooling but it works equally well for heating.

Secondly, $(1)$ can be re-written as an ODE because:

$$\dot{Q}=-mC_p\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{2}$$

where $m$ is the total mass of air in the room and $C_p$ the specific heat capacity of air.

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get, reworked:

$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{T(t)-T_{env}}=\frac{hA}{mC_p}\mathrm{d}t\tag{3}$$

Set $\alpha=\frac{hA}{mC_p}$, then:
$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{T(t)-T_{env}}=\alpha\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}$$
$(4)$ integrates to:

$$\ln\left[\frac{T_{end}-T_{env}}{T_{begin}-T_{env}}\right]=-\alpha t$$

which gives you the temperature evolution of $T_{begin}\to T_{end}$ (room). It also tells you which factors influence it and how. **Given enough time ($t\to +\infty$) the toom temperature will equal the radiator temperature**.

Note of course that this is a idealisation that relies on some factors, like $T_{env}$, to be constant.

> I want to get some idea whether it has some effect or is basically
> negligible in a real world application and if it does affect the
> room's temperature, how long would it take to do that.

This will largely depend on factors like $h, A, m$ and $T_{env}$, as evidenced above.

---

$h\approx 20\mathrm{W/(m^2 K)}$

$A=3.6\mathrm{m^2}$

$VC_p=90750\mathrm{W/K}$

$\alpha=\frac{hA}{VC_p}=8\times 10^{-4}\mathrm{s^{-1}}$

Calculate time for room to reach $90$ percent of $25^{\circ}$, which  is $22.5^{\circ}$.

$\ln\left[\frac{T_{end}-T_{env}}{T_{begin}-T_{env}}\right]=\ln\left[\frac{22.5-25}{20-25}\right]=\ln 0.5$

$t=-\frac{\ln 0.5}{\alpha}=866\mathrm{s}=14\mathrm{min}$

Comment: Ok thanks for your detailed answer but I don't really get any of those equations. Can you give an example answer based on a certain room size and radiator size? I'm not a student of physics, I just was interested to know a rough idea of what influence it would have.

Comment: Let's give some random example values for ℎ,,  and  then - what would we get? Let's say, you've got a room with a size of your choice, and a radiator as long as the longest wall.

Comment: "Can you give an example answer based on a certain room size and radiator size?" The problem is finding a good value for $h$. Also, please specify room size (it's **your** question.

Comment: Just use 5x5x3 metres then. The radiator would be like .6 metres high. No idea what `h` would be or what would affect that. It's your answer so I'll let you come up with an appropriate value for that.

Comment: You'll have to give me time. Numerically it is laborious.

Comment: Yeah the equations don't look simple, that's why with this I was no nearer to the answer than when I started. So what affects h then? I thought most rooms filled with regular air are basically the same - what factors are there?

Comment: *So what affects h then?* As a non-phys you don't want to go there. One factor that affects it is flow speed (around the radiator(s))

Comment: Well I meant real world factors that affect h, like we have the size of the room and the radiator and that the room is filled with air. Those are the only factors we know..and that the room has relatively decent insulation like double glazing and whatnot.

Comment: No, $h$ is an intrinsic value, only affected by radiator/air interface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient

Comment: Ok. the estimate, for what it's worth, is ready.

Comment: Hmm ok interesting result. Does that take into account heat lost from the room? Since in reality, or at least in my own experience, radiators set at normal low temperatures (≈ 60 degrees as you say), or even at much higher settings take way longer than 14 mins to raise the temperature of average rooms up from 20 to 22.5.

Comment: No, perfect insulation is assumed. The time is short because 20 C is already quite high. To reach 99 % of 25  C requires 1 hour.

Comment: Hmm...then to get a realistic answer, more realistic insulation would have to be used. Otherwise we could calculate similarly that a human being standing in a room would also raise the temperature of the room rather well while in reality there's a negligible effect - especially within a short space of time. Something like normal walls with double glazed windows. I don't suppose you'd have any idea how to calculate that?

Comment: A human would heat the room, absolutely. *I don't suppose you'd have any idea how to calculate that?* Really you need a a far, far more sophisticated model or an empirical approach. Both are outside the scope of this question due to dazzling complexity. Sorry!

Comment: No, a human would heat the room to his body temperature only with perfect insulation. In real life we don't live in houses that have no need central heating that we heat with our own body temperature. Anyway I guess it's too difficult to calculate that as you say. Unfortunately your 14 minutes in the real world without perfect insulation might actually be like 9 days perhaps....or even _never_ since a human can obviously never heat a room to his own body temperature...like ever.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to say that “90% of $25^\circ\rm C$ is $22.5^\circ\rm C$,” because the Celsius temperature scale has an arbitrary zero point. What you’ve computed here is the half-life of the temperature difference between the radiator and the room, as the room exponentially approaches the radiator’s temperature. That half-life depends entirely on parameters which seem to be specified in the comments, but not in the answer, which is confusing. It’s also not clear in the answer that you’re only describing the evolution of a perfectly-insulated room.

Answer (score 0):

If the temperature of the radiator is higher than the temperature of the room then there will be a flow of heat from the radiator to the room. The rate at which heat flows into the room will be proportional to the difference between the radiator temperature and the room temperature.

If the room is hermetically sealed and perfectly insulated then the temperature of the room and everything in it will increase until it reaches the same temperature as the radiator. The time that this takes (or, more exactly, the time it takes for the room temperature to get close to the radiator temperature, since exact equality will take an infinite length of time) will depend on many factors, including the size of the room, the size and material of the radiator, the contents of the room. This case is dealt with in detail in Gert's answer. Note that in no circumstances can the radiator heat the room to a temperature that is higher than the radiator temperature - this would violate the second law of thermodynamics.

However, in reality it is likely that the room will *not* be hermetically sealed and perfectly insulated, and the temperature of the outside environment is likely to be no higher than the room temperature. In this case, as the room temperature rises, there will be a flow of heat energy from the room to the outside environment. The steady state room temperature will now be the temperature at which the rate of heat flow from the room to the outside equals the rate of heat flow from the radiator into the room - this will be lower than the radiator temperature but greater than the outside temperature.

So the best we can say for a real room is that given enough time the radiator will heat the room to some temperature between $20^o$C and $25^o$C, depending upon how well sealed and insulated the room is.

Comment: "will heat the room to some temperature between 20C and 25C, depending upon how well sealed and insulated the room is." Surely this would also depend on the size of the radiators and the room somewhat, otherwise the room would also by the same logic increase to the body temperature of a person standing in the room.

Comment: @hasen Yes, depending on all those factors too. You seem to be looking for a theoretical answer to a question that you can really only answer empirically (by measurement) because of all the different variable factors involved.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a theoretical answer - as stated in my question 'Make up your own approximate values for these'....all is needed is an example radiator and room. In a perfect environment, anything inside a room with a constant temperature higher than the room it's in would increase the room's temperature to match. But not practical at all in real terms otherwise we wouldn't need heating at all since we'd heat the rooms with our own bodies.

Comment: @Hasen When I said "theoretical" I meant you are hoping for a formula into which you can plug a few simple parameters and out comes an answer. But there are too many variables in this scenario. Simple physics formulae are often derived by ignoring most variables, making some simplifying assumptions, and focussing on the two or three variables that make the biggest difference to the result. But in this scenario that approach does not work - too many significant variables and everything depends on everything else. This is also why there is no simple formula for tomorrow's weather, for example.

Comment: Again... _no_ I was not looking for that.. I was looking for ONE example of one room with a certain size and a certain size radiator and how long it would take to heat....with realistic wall insulation - not perfect. Again, no theories, no general formulas...honestly was not what I was looking for at all.

Comment: In fact I wasn't necessarily even looking for anything mathematical, scientific or otherwise precise either, it's up to whoever answers to give their insight but I would've also been happy to accept an answer like 'the real world effect would be basically negligible'....(if that were indeed the case)....from someone with a lot of experience in this area. Since as Gert stated, most radiators have a low setting of at least 60 degrees so it would be likely pointless to switch them on at 25 degrees only.

Comment: @Hasen Ah, well, if you want a *practical* answer you could try https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://diy.stackexchange.com/